# sometimes after standby screen is not visible

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

sometimes after wake up from standby the blank screen is coming.
as per log launcherFragment is visible but its not visible to user.

```
           getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(backStackChangedListener);
                LauncherFragment launcherFragment = new LauncherFragment();
                FragmentManager supportFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.uiLayout, launcherFragment, LauncherFragment.TAG);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(LauncherFragment.TAG);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```

Note: While using the TalkBack I am able to hear the all the view but the UI is not visible to user.

Also getting the getVisibility value is 0, getAlpha value 1.0.

Could somebody please help me here why sometimes after standby screen is not visible to user.

Comment: Can you post the `LauncherFragment` it may have something wrong with it when its re-attaching itself?

Comment: Hi @avalerio, in Launcher fragment adding the child fragment that is display the card.